# How to enable write access in internal hard drive in ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, partition, ntfs

I am a windows 10 user but recently i shifted to Ubuntu 17.10. I am not able to write  on my internal drive partition so i googled and found the ntfs configuration tool and then I installed Ntfs configuration tool but can't open it.

It shows "Failed to run ntfs-config as user root.". Then i opened the terminal and ran the command sudo ntfs-config and entered the password and it again shows this error.

```
No protocol specified
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
No protocol specified
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/NtfsConfig/Fstab/SimpleGladeApp.py:335: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
return gtk.glade.XML(self.glade_path, root, domain)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/NtfsConfig/Fstab/SimpleGladeApp.py:335: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
return gtk.glade.XML(self.glade_path, root, domain)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/NtfsConfig/Fstab/SimpleGladeApp.py:335: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
return gtk.glade.XML(se)...and so on can anybody help me with this? I have only 1 day of experience with linux.
```

Comment: As the error message tells you, it should not be executed as root. Did you try to run it as a normal user?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Comment: Yes, i did that but still shows the error. @Yeti